How to Make a Sticky Element Relative to Body Without Moving it Outside Parent Container?
I have a layout where one of the flex items inside a flex container is set to position: sticky. It works as expected within the parent container, but I want it to behave as sticky relative to the body instead, without moving it outside of the parent container. Here's my current code:
<div>
  <div class="non-stick-header">mini non-stick header</div>
  
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="no-sticky">No sticky</div>
    <div class="sticky">sticky container</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="scroll-content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...
  </div>
</div>

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.non-stick-header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: grey;
}

.no-sticky {
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
} 

.scroll-content {
    height: 1000px;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;;
}



Currently, the .sticky element only stays sticky within its parent .flex-container. How can I make it sticky relative to the body while keeping it inside the flex container in the HTML structure?
unfortunately i need to keep flex-container to switch element directions based on condiiton
Thank you for any suggestions!
https://jsfiddle.net/4rbkh6z0/

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example
"sticky
The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.
This value always creates a new stacking context. Note that a sticky element "sticks" to its nearest ancestor that has a "scrolling mechanism" (created when overflow is hidden, scroll, auto, or overlay), even if that ancestor isn't the nearest actually scrolling ancestor."
It means if u want it to be relative to first parent or body ... make that content scrollable and hide all internal scrollbars
.scroll-container {
    overflow: scroll;
    min-height: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.scroll-content {
    height: 500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

parent div - <div class="scroll-container">
Example for reference-
https://jsfiddle.net/guestMe/g5zytwef/6/
